# Pair Apple Wireless Keyboard 3rd gen with Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: bluetooth, 16.04, wireless-keyboards

I get continuously failed with bluetooth. 
Mighty mouse then again paired nicely.

System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
Keyboard: Apple Wireless Keyboard 3rd gen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to work around this issue by using the "blueman" package to pair the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks. Blueman works.

Seems to be a regression in the default bluetooth package as from 15.04.

Comment: Great manager! I managed to pair and connect Mighty Mouse and Apple Keyboard 3rd both. Both causesd a bug report which I sent to developers.